# R rep function with overwriting elements

Tags: r, rep

Given a vector such as

```
> x
 [1] 1 1 2 1 1 1 5 1 1 1 5 7 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I want to replicate the elements n times --BUT--
I want the old elements to be overwritten by the replications.
Using the basic rep functions gives:

```
> rep(x,x)
 [1] 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 5 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

this is just shifting the original un-shifted adjacent elements to the right.
But if I were to repeatedly overwrite each of the adjacent elements with the
replicated values (step by step here with left to right replacement by each element), I would have something like...

```
112111511157111111111
112211511157111111111
112211555557111111111
112211555555555111111
112211555557777777111
```

Notice, for every N times replicated element it just overwrites the N adjacent right neighbors.  I could do this in a loop, but is there a fast vector based approach to do it?

na.locf is close (pre-setting 1s to NA), but (as I understand it) it will fill ALL or a fixed number only of rightmost NAs with the rep value, rather than exactly N right neighbors.

A possible alternative would be to have all zeros in the place of original ones, and only repeat and overwrite elements N times with binary one values.
e.g. above would be...
ex:

```
x<-  c(0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
sig<-c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

edit: to clarify, it should compactly extend to any number of repeatable elements 
(same as rep function).

Comment: for the first problem, some clever combination of `embed`, `inverse.rle`, and indexing, perhaps, but not tonight for me.

Comment: I didn't even know I could invert rle. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: x is length 21 your answer is length 22. Should it be "001100111111111111000" which is length 21?

Comment: apologies if I miscounted by hand. I've revised it to align. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
y <- x
for (i in unique(y)) {             # or perhaps sort(unique(y))
   for (j in which(y==i)) {
      x[seq(j, length.out=i)] <- i 
   }
}

x
## [1] 1 1 2 2 1 1 5 5 5 5 5 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c(0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

dumFun <- function(a,b,c){rep(c(0,1,0), times = c(a-1,b,max(c-b-a+1,0)))}
1*Reduce('|', 
      mapply(dumFun, a = seq_along(x), b = x, c =length(x), SIMPLIFY= FALSE))

 [1] 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

This produces a list of vectors of zeros padded with 1's as per x. It then applies the OR operation successively to each element of the list.

We can wrap this in a function:

```
getSignal <- function(x){
    dumFun <- function(a,b,c){
                    rep(c(0,1,0), times = c(a,b,max(c-b-a,0)))
                  }
    1*Reduce('|', 
        mapply(dumFun, a = seq_along(x)-1, b = x, c =length(x),
                                                       SIMPLIFY= FALSE))
}
```

we can also apply a similar idea to handle the first problem:

```
getRep <- function(x){
    dumFun <- function(a,b,c){
                    rep(c(0,b,0), times = c(a,b,max(c-b-a,0)))
          }
    Reduce('pmax',
        mapply(dumFun, a = seq_along(x)-1, b = x, c =length(x),
                                                       SIMPLIFY= FALSE))
}

y <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
getRep(y)
 [1] 1 1 2 2 1 1 5 5 5 5 5 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 1 1 1
```